# How do I assign a value in a macro from macro parameter in groff?

Tags: linux, unix, groff, troff

I am trying to define macro .ML which will define record pO with the value from record hM which is defined through parameter 1.

This is what I tried:

```
.de ML
.nr hM \\$1
.nr pO \(hM
..
.ML 0.5
Introduction

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

.bp
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

And this is the error I get:

```
template.troff:5: warning: numeric expression expected (got a special character)
```

I suspect I am missing an important point on how records work in groff.

Comment: `hM` is a numeric register, so use `.nr pO \n(hM`.

Comment: But I am already using `.nr pO \n(hM`

Comment: No, in the listing above, the `n` after the backslash is missing.